# Pandas add multiple rows with IF condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe cosisting of city bicycle trips. However, I have some problems with handling trips that exceed over one hour(I want to use YYYYmmDDhh as a composite key in my data model). So what I want to do is to create a column "keyhour" that I could connect with other tables. This would be YYYYmmDDhh based on started_at IF start_hour == end_hour. However, if end_hour is greater than start_hour, I want to insert that many rows with the same TourID to my dataframe, in order to indicate that the trip has lasted few hours.

```
                        started_at                         ended_at  duration  start_station_id    start_station_name start_station_description  ...  end_station_description  end_station_latitude  end_station_longitude TourID start_hour  end_hour
0 2020-05-01 03:03:14.941000+00:00 2020-05-01 03:03:14.941000+00:00       635               484        Karenlyst allé            ved Skabos vei  ...      langs Drammensveien             59.914145              10.715505      0          3         3
1 2020-05-01 03:05:48.529000+00:00 2020-05-01 03:05:48.529000+00:00       141               455  Sofienbergparken sør      langs Sofienberggata  ...            ved Sars gate             59.921206              10.769989      1          3         3
2 2020-05-01 03:13:33.156000+00:00 2020-05-01 03:13:33.156000+00:00       330               550         Thereses gate   ved Bislett trikkestopp  ...    ved Kristian IVs gate             59.914767              10.740971      2          3         3
3 2020-05-01 03:14:14.549000+00:00 2020-05-01 03:14:14.549000+00:00       479               597           Fredensborg         ved rundkjøringen  ...            ved Oslo City             59.912334              10.752292      3          3         3
4 2020-05-01 03:20:12.355000+00:00 2020-05-01 03:20:12.355000+00:00       629               617  Bjerregaardsgate Øst          ved Uelands gate  ...          langs Oslo gate             59.908255              10.767800      4          3         3
```

So for example if started_at = 2020-05-01 03:03:14.941000+00:00, ended_at = 2020-05-01 06:03:14.941000+00:00 , start_hour = 3, end_hour = 6 and TourID = 1, I want to have rows with:

keyhour   ;      TourID

```
2020050103  ;1

2020050104   ;1

2020050105   ;1

2020050106   ;1
```

And all other values(duration etc) related to this trip id.

However, I really cannot find any way to do it in Pandas. Is it possible or do I have to use pure python to re-write my source csv?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is `df` and that you have `import pandas as pd`

```
# convert to datetime and rounddown to hour
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at']).dt.floor(freq='H') 
df['ended_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ended_at']).dt.floor(freq='H')

# this creates a list of hourly datetime ranges from started_at to ended_at
df['keyhour'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(x['started_at'], x['ended_at'], freq="1H")), axis='columns') 

# this just expands to row each element in the list of keyhour column
df = df.explode('keyhour') 

# conversts it to a string, of the format you specified
df['keyhour'] = df['keyhour'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H') 

df
```